# Hashids not working in .NET when decoding

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, hash, hashids

I am using [Hashids](http://hashids.org/net/) to hide database IDs in the URL. Following is my initialization of Hashids:

```
public static Security.Hashids HashOps = new Security.Hashids("Sl212", 5);
```

`Security` is my project's namespace inside which I copied Hashids.cs file. The encoding is working correctly but decoding is throwing `IndexOutOfRangeException` exception. This is how I am decoding:

```
int fileID=HashOps.Decode(FileID)[0];
```

I tried it on many salts and without salt, but its throwing the same exception again and again. I am using the original code from the file. Except namespace I changed nothing.

Please tell me what to do? After trying for 12 hours my mind is stuck at dead end.

**UPDATE**

A test code I am running in Console app also throwing exception:

```
Hashids HashOps = new Hashids();
string hash = HashOps.Encode(212);
Console.WriteLine("Encoded: " + hash);
Console.WriteLine("Decoded: " + HashOps.Decode(hash)[0]);
```

Comment: Please provide a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve): Just create a minimal example that (1) creates a Hashids instance, (2) encodes some value, (3) decodes it and throws the exception as shown in your question.

Comment: Why are you using Hashids to hide database IDs in the URL?

Comment: @AsadSaeeduddin I preferred this because it has no collisions and has a decode method to get back the ID. If you have any other suggestions then please tell.

Comment: Any suggestions would depend on what you're trying to gain from hiding the DB ids. You're not really getting any security from using hashids, you can always decode it without the salt.

Comment: @AsadSaeeduddin Even without the salt its throwing exception. See my update.

Comment: @Heinzi I updated my question with a test code.

Comment: @AishwaryaShiva: Thanks. Please show the *encoding* part as well, i.e., replace `string hash = "vb4Vk";` with `string hash = new Hashids().Encode(42);` (or whatever else you used to create `vb4Vk`).

Comment: @Heinzi I updated my code. But its now working fine on Console but not in my web application. Please wait till tomorrow. I will recheck my complete web application code and then tell you.

Comment: @AishwaryaShiva: That's what I suspected (that the problem was somewhere else) - and that's why minimal, complete examples are such great debugging tools. :-) Good night! (My *guess* is that you are using different salts for encoding and decoding, but I'll let you check your code first.)

Comment: Thanks a lot @Heinzi . I solved it. See my answer. :)

Comment: @Heinzi One more thing I want to ask. My web application is public and anyone can create account on it. Also, it will contain important user data like sales stats, corporate management stats etc. So, should I use salt or not?

Comment: @AishwaryaShiva: Firstly, you should do permission checks whenever you do something. Don't trust user input (such as URL parameters). Always check whether the current user is really allowed to view a certain requested resource or not. **Hashids are not a security feature.** To quote from their homepage: "*Do you have a question or comment that involves "security" and "hashids" in the same sentence? **Don't use Hashids.***".

Comment: @Heinzi I am doing all permissions check. Actually, I don't wanted user to know content ID when accessing through public API. But thanks a lot for your suggestions. I am using salt and 5 minimum length for the hash. :)

Comment: Thanks for idea.  fix my Hashid for our asp net core 3.x..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally, with the help of @Heinzi I was able to detect what was really going on. The problem was with my web application's URL detection system. Which detects the URL and loads the content in a DIV. That system was making the complete URL lower cased. Hence, changing the hash containing the capital letter. I just used the actual URL instead of lowered one when detecting IDs.